# Simulated Annealing - How to set up an appropriate neighbourhood configuration for a complex problem?

Tags: optimization, simulated-annealing

I am working on a project that attempts to use simulated annealing to organise various items into designated sections while maintaining some stability requirements.

For this problem the neighbourhood configuration should remove two or more of these items and switch their places (there are exactly as many items as there are places for them), but I am unsure of how calculated or random this switch should be.

When testing if the stability requirements are fulfilled, I am able to tell vaguely how items should be repositioned in order to improve the stability, but should the neighbourhood configuration take this into account? Or will that make the algorithm too "greedy"?

Any help/direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with simulated annealing problems, but I don't know what you mean by 'neighbourhood configuration'. My scenario used the following rules: 1) if making the simulation lower energy, always accept the exchange 2) if making the simulation higher energy, calculate a probability of exchange using the [Boltzmann factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) and randomise a yes/no for acceptance. "Energy" is abstracted as counting all the non-same-type nearest neighbour interactions and subtracting all the same-type interactions, so that segregating into regions of similar neighbours is energetically favourable.

Comment: What I mean by the neighbourhood configuration (this is how it has been referenced in the papers I've been reading) is the process of generating a new solution with each iteration. I am unsure as to how a new solution should be generated in my case - I know it should have some element of randomness, but am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: In my case the sites are chains representing polymers and require that each unit in the chain maintain one nearest neighbour distance to the next, so fitting them into physically feasible positions is tricky! The simulation runs a 'hot' equilibriation phase making mixing transitions relatively feasible and tracks overall energy change to judge that it is at equilibrium. The Boltzmann distribution is still important to avoid creating unphysical arrangements; it's just scaled so that it accepts unfavourable transitions relatively often.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. Before assessing the cost/energy of a solution and evaluating the probability of it being accepted, a new solution within the neighbourhood of the previous solution must be generated. I am concerned with how to generate this new solution, not evaluating whether or not to accept it.

Comment: I suppose I'm not grasping what you mean by 'how'. Beyond 'write some code that does that', what does a useful answer look like?